# Proving that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2 + 1\rangle$  is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have some general idea of going about this. I'm trying to come up with a suitable mapping. I've come up with $\phi\colon a + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle\longmapsto a$ where $a$ is an irreducible element in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ but this mapping has some issues. For example take
$5x + x^2 + 1$, which is $5x \pmod{x^2+1}$. $5x$ does not belong to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. So my question is, is there a better mapping?

I know for a fact that if you add any integer call it $b$ to $\langle x^2 + 1\rangle$, you will get $b$ back which belongs to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. I'm stuck when $b$ is not an integer.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $\phi$.

Comment: How do you define Z[i]?

Comment: Its the ring of Gaussian integers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer

Comment: @Person: yes, and how do you define the ring of Gaussian integers? Some people define it to be $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$. I still don't understand your definition of $\phi$. What is $a'$?

Comment: @Person: Your proposed mapping does not even make sense. The elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ are represented by **polynomials** with integer coefficients. The elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are not polynomials.

Comment: @Person, but how do you define it?

Comment: @Person, see my answer for why I am asking "how do you defined Z[i]".

Comment: Couldn't you simply map $x$ to $i$?

Comment: Since $\mathbb Z[i]$ is defined as $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2 + 1\rangle$ they are equal and hence the identity function is an isomorphism.

Comment: No definition of Z[i] is given, the question is meaningless.

Comment: @Pearson, I know what the Gaussian integers are, I'm asking how *you* defined Z[i].

Comment: You can't prove theorem without definition.

Comment: Voting to close as **not a real question**

Comment: @quanta: There are many standard ways of defining $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Defining it as a quotient is just one of them. You can also define it as the smallest subring of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $\mathbb{Z}$ and $i$, which is a pretty standard and which happens to agree with the notation $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: Dear Person, This is one of several algebra questions you have asked in fairly rapid succession.  One previous question was about the *meaning* of the notation $\langle x,3\rangle$.   Before that, you asked a question about $\langle 2,x\rangle$ in which you included a precise *definition* of the notation in the question.  You declined to explain why you were asking a new question about notation that you had already defined yourself in an earlier question.   Without further explanation, it makes me wonder if you are somewhat lost in the algebra course that you are taking.  Have you tried ...

Comment: ... discussing some of your questions directly with your professor, your TA, or other students in the class?  Regards,

Answer (score 11):

When you want to show that a quotient is isomorphic to a given object (ring, group, semigroup, etc), it is usually simplest to get the Isomorphism Theorem to do your work for you. Instead of trying to define an isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, which will usually require you to show the map is well-defined, try to find a **surjective** map from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ whose kernel is exactly $\langle x^2+1\rangle$. Then the Isomorphism Theorem guarantees the existence of an isomorphism
$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\langle x^2+1\rangle} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\mathrm{ker}(\phi)} \cong \mathbb{Z}[i].$$

Now, to define a map from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, it is enough to specify what happens to the coefficients and what happens to $x$. There is an obvious thing to do with the coefficients (just let them be). Is there an obvious thing you can map $x$ to? I think there is. Then check what the kernel of this map, and let the Isomorphism Theorem do all the hard work. After all, that's why we proved it in the first place.

---

Well, apparently that's not the case here, as the Isomorphism Theorems have not been proven yet in your class.

Still: it's usually annoying to define a map *from* a quotient to a ring; because the elements of the quotient are equivalence classes, and that usually means that you need to show that your definition of map does not depend on the representative. It's much easier to map **into** a quotient. So instead of trying to find an isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ *to* $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, it might be easier to find a map $\varphi$ **from** $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ **to** $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Given an element $a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$, with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, where should we map it? We certainly want to map $1$ to $1 + \langle x^2+1\rangle$ (identity to identity). Which means we want to map $a$ to $a+\langle x^2+1\rangle$. Which means that the *only* thing we need to do is figure out what to do with $i$. If we map $i$ to $p(x)+\langle x^2+1\rangle$, then this will completely determine our homomorphism, since
$$\begin{align*}
\varphi(a+bi) &= \varphi(a) + \varphi(b)\varphi(i)\\
 &= a+\langle x^2+1\rangle + \left(b+\langle x^2+1\rangle\right)\left(p(x)+\langle x^2+1\rangle\right)\\
 &= a + bp(x)\langle x^2+1\rangle.\end{align*}$$

Okay, what should $\varphi(i)$ be? Since $\varphi(i)^2 = \varphi(i^2) = \varphi(-1) = -1+\langle x^2+1\rangle$, we need $\varphi(i)$ to be the congruence class of a polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $p^2(x)\equiv -1\pmod{\langle x^2+1\rangle}$. Is there some simple choice that might work? Again, I think there is; check to see that it actually works.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[i]$ be the evaluation homomorphism and use the first isomorphism theorem.

---

Edit: Added for confusion on both evaluation homomorphism and first isomorphism theorem.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Then $R[x]$ is defined to be ring consisting of all polynomials in $x$ with coefficients in $R$. So for $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, we have elements such as $5, x^2+1,$ and $3x^7-9x^3+4$. We can naturally extend this definition to adjoin arbitrary elements instead of a placeholder variable. In particular, we can think of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ as the ring of all polynomials in $i$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. With some thought we realize that this is precisely equivalent to the normal definition of the Gaussian integers since $i^2=-1$ (i.e. polynomials in $i$ of degree greater than 1 can be reduced to the form $a+bi$).

Going back to polynomial rings, let $\psi: R \rightarrow S$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings. Then there is a conceptually natural way to extend this homomorphism to a homomorphism $\varphi: R[x] \rightarrow S$. By our definition of $R[x]$, every element can be written as $\sum r_i x^i$, with the $r_i \in R$. Then, since $\varphi$ is to be a homomorphism,
$$\varphi(\sum r_i x^i) =  \sum \varphi(r_i) \varphi(x)^i$$
So $\varphi$ is completely determined by the image of $R$ and $x$. Since our desire is to extend $\psi$ naturally, it makes sense to send all elements of $R$ to their image under $\psi$. So we only need choose what $x$ should be mapped to.

From this we can define the *evaluation homomorphism* between $R[x]$ and $R[\alpha]$ to be the evaluation of any polynomial in $R[x]$ at $x=\alpha$. So $\sum r_i x^i \mapsto \sum r_i \alpha^i$. Take time to convince yourself that it is a completely natural definition and that it is, in fact, unique. In addition to that, it is not hard to show that the homomorphism must be surjective.

To return to your example, let $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[i]$ be the evaluation homomorphism. Then we have a natural, well-defined ring homomorphism and can look at its image. For any $a + bi \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, $\varphi(a+bx) = a+bi$. So we see, as mentioned above, that $\varphi$ is surjective. Then we can use the first isomorphism theorem to say that $\mathbb{Z}[i] \simeq \mathbb{Z}[x]/\ker \varphi$.

Finally, the first isomorphism theorem states for any ring homomorphism $\varphi: R \rightarrow S$, $\text{im } \varphi \simeq R / \ker \varphi$. So if $\varphi$ is surjective, as is the case here, then $S \simeq R / \ker \varphi$.

Comment: If the OP knew what "the" evaluation homomorphism was, I don't think he/she would be asking this question.

Comment: I don't understand how that mapping works. We're modding everything out by x^2 + 1

Comment: @Person: Are you familiar with the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: No. My professor never talked about that.

Comment: Person: so when you mod out Z[x] by $x^2$+1, you are left with all polynomials of degree-1 or degree 0, i.e., all expressions ax+b, where a,b are both integers. The isomorphism is then: ax+b-->ai+b

Comment: @Qiaochu: Dear Qiaochu, There may be many reasons that this particular OP is asking questions, basic confusion about everything in their algebra course being one possible reason.  See my comment below Arturo's answer for more explanation/jusfication for this.  Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Here is a perhaps slightly more concrete way of looking at things.  In the longer run, the more abstract approaches are essential.

What are the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$?  They are *equivalence classes*.  Two polynomials are called equivalent if they differ by a multiple of the polynomial $x^2+1$.

In our situation, we can give a more concrete description of the equivalence classes.  Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients.  Imagine dividing $P(x)$ by $x^2+1$, using the ordinary procedure for dividing polynomials.  We get in general a remainder which is a polynomial of the shape $bx+a$ (one or both of $a$ and $b$ may be $0$).

So we have
$$P(x)=Q(x)(x^2+1) +bx+a$$
where $Q(x)$ is the quotient.  If you look at the above displayed formula, you will see that $P(x)$ and $bx+a$ are equivalent. Formally,
$$P(x) +(x^2+1)= bx+a + (x^2+1)$$
It is easy to see that if $bx+a$ and $dx+c$ are *different* polynomials, then they determine different equivalence classes, since their difference is not divisible by $x^2+1$.  Thus every equivalence class corresponds to a unique polynomial of the form $bx+a$.

This is analogous to what happens with congruence modulo $m$.  The collection of equivalence classes there is $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$, but we can think of $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$ as (sort of) $0, 1, 2, \dots, m-1$ with a funny addition and multiplication.

Now where should we send $a+bx+(x^2+1)$?  By basic properties of isomorphism, once we know where $1+(x^2+1)$ and $x+(x^2+1)$ are to go, the rest is determined. It is natural, indeed necessary, to send the equivalence class of $1$ to $a+bi$, where $a=1$ and $b=0$.

Where should $x+(x^2+1)$ go?  It is reasonable to send it to $i$.  So then the general object $a+bx +(x^2+1)$ should go to $a+bi$.

Does this work?  You need to show this mapping is one-to-one and onto, or to use more currently approved language, that the mapping is a bijection.  That is easy, given the prior discussion.

Then we need to show that the mapping "preserves" addition and multiplication.  The fact that addition is preserved is mechanical.  Multiplication is a bit trickier.  The product
$$[P(x)+(x^2+1)][Q(x)+(x^2+1)]$$
is, by definition, $P(x)Q(x)+(x^2+1)$.

Apply this to $P(x)=a+bx$, $Q(x)=c+dx$.
Note that $(a+bx)(c+dx)=ac +bdx^2 +(ad+bc)x$.

But $bdx^2=bd(x^2+1)-bd$, so $bdx^2$ is equivalent to $-bd$.
Putting things together, we find that 
$(a+bx)(c+dx)$ is equivalent to $ac-bd +(ad+bc)x$.  This should remind you of the rule for multiplying complex numbers, and help to take care of showing that the mapping behaves well under multiplication.

**A bit of intuition** The polynomial $x^2+1$ is equivalent to the $0$-polynomial, since they differ by a multiple of $x^2+1$.  So in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$, "$x^2+1$" behaves like $0$, so "$x^2$" behaves like "$-1$". Thus the square of "$x$" is "$-1$".

More formally,
$$[x+(x^2+1)]^2 =x^2+(x^2+1) =-1+(x^2+1)$$

**Note:** There is another mapping that would give an isomorphism, namely the one that takes $a+bx +(x^2+1)$ to $a-bi$.